# Why could Yvonne Hartman attack the other Cybermen?

Tags: doctor-who

In "Doomsday" Yvonne becomes a Cyberman and presumably loses all emotion and sense of personal identity. Yet, she resists their control at the end, and kills her own "kind." How? What makes her so special from the thousands of Cybermen before her? As far as I know, no one else has ever been able to assert control once they've been transformed.

Comment: [Lazy Writing](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DeusExMachina)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Closing Time* is another episode where someone defeats the mind control of the Cybermen. As well as that Cyberwoman in the *Torchwood* episode *Cyberwoman* (Season 1 Episode 4). It seems as if there is a strong enough emotion (or the process didn't complete for some reason) the person will get over the Cyber control.

Comment: S08E12, "Death In Heaven", shows multiple characters with strong emotional attachments overriding their Cyberman psyche.  In one of the cases, it's implied that the character had not completed his emotional purging process, but there's no indication the other character hadn't been fully processed prior to overriding the Cyber control.